# Making mysql queries dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am very new to codeigniter and working in a test project. I have an array name `$array=array('name','id')`
if, the array has only one element like 'name', then I need the below line of code:

```
$this->db->like("name", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
```

if the array has more than one element, then I need to have below codes

```
$this->db->like("name", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
$this->db->or_like("id", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
```

If i have more than two elements like (name, id, email, mobile etc), i want to achieve the below codes dynamically

```
$this->db->like("name", $_POST["search"]["value"]);  
$this->db->or_like("id", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
$this->db->or_like("email", $_POST["search"]["value"]);  
$this->db->or_like("mobile", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
```

etc....

Comment: Well loop over the `$_POST["search"]` array then

Answer (score 0):

get each input field value

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$id = $this->input->post('id');
```

then use

```
if (!empty($name)) {$this->db->like('name', $name);}
if (!empty($id)) {$this->db->like('id', $id);}
```